# Automatically fill an empty prenote field when quoting with csquotes

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

I use `biblatex` with `csquotes`. If I quote indirectly I use `\autocite` and if I quote directly I use `csquotes` `\blockcqute`. I'd like to insert predefined text into the `prenote` field of the `\blockcqute` (or csquotes commands in general) if it was ommited or if it is empty – so that
`\blockcquote[][55]{Author}{Quote}` is similar to writing `\blockcquote[See][55]{Author}{Quote}`.
What I found is that I could redefine biblatex's postnote macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {% true
        \printtext{See}%
    }{% false
        \printfield{prenote}}%
        \setunit{\prenotedelim%
    }%
}
```

But then writing `Some text \autocite[][55]{Author}` would be similar to `Some text \autocite[See][55]{Author}` as well and this is not what I want to achieve.

So, is there any hook like biblatex's prenote macro I could modify?

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way is to hook into `\mkccitation` and add your redefinition of the `prenote` macro

```
\renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {\printtext{See}}
      {\printfield{prenote}}%
    \setunit{\prenotedelim}}%
    \space#1}
```

this redefinition will be limited to `csquotes`' citation commands only - it happens within a group.